# Recursive DTO in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to create a DTO from my `@Entity` called `Category`, but I'm not able to figure out how to handle recursion in the constructor.

The issue is that in the `Category` there is an attribute `List<Category> subcategories;` of subcategories. Here is the `table` and `@Entity` snippet of the model:

```sql
create table CATEGORY (
    CATEGORY_ID NUMBER not null,
    NAME VARCHAR2(50) not null,
    PARENT_ID NUMBER,
    IMAGE_URL VARCHAR2(256),
    ORDER_NUMBER NUMBER(11)
)
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATEGORY")
public class ProductCategory {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Integer parent_id;

    @Column(name = "IMAGE_URL")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_NUMBER")
    private Integer orderNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private ProductCategory parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @OrderBy("orderNumber")
    private List<Category> subcategories;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Product.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CATEGORY_ID")
    private List<Product> products;

    // some other attributes and getters and setters
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to convert the entity `Category` to `CategoryDTO`, but I struggle with the constructor:

```java
public class CategoryDTO {
    private final Integer categoryId;

    private final String imageUrl;

    private final List<ProductDTO> products;

    private final List<CategoryDTO> subcategories;

    @Inject
    public ProductCategoryDTO(final Category cat) {
        this.categoryId = cat.getId();
        this.imageUrl = cat.getImageUrl();
        this.articles = cat.getArticles()
            .stream()
            .map(Product::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.subcategories = // here I want to call something like this() to convert
                             // subcategories of type Category to CategoryDTO
    }
    // other methods
```

How can I handle recursion in the constructor of DTO object?

Comment: How about `cat.getSubcategories().stream().map(CategoryDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toList())`?

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to be working as expected.

Note: If ProductCategoryDTO(...) is your constructor, rename it as your file name and use the same.

```
    public CategoryDTO(final Category cat) {
        this.categoryId = cat.getId();
        this.imageUrl = cat.getImageUrl();
        this.articles = cat.getArticles()
            .stream()
            .map(Product::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        this.subcategories = cat.getSubcategories()
            .stream()
            .map(CategoryDTO::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    }
```